# Express get error

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express

I am setting up routes to my application controller on a node server -

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/<path>/<query type>', function(req, res) {
//Expecting query parameter <query type>?name=<something>

var query = req.query.name;
var path = '/<path>/<query type>?name='+query;

var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 8080,
  path: path,
  method: 'GET'
};

var reques  = http.request(options, function(response) {

  console.log('STATUS' + response.statusCode);

  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    res.json(chunk);res.end(chunk);
  });
});

reques.on('error', function(e) {
console.error(e);
});
reques.end();
});

app.listen(7001);
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
console.error(err.stack);
res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});
```

I want to respond with the variable "chunk" at 7001. But here I am getting some compilation errors -

app.get('/*path*/*query type*', function(req, res) {
    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your app like this

```
var app = require('express')();
```

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot to write that. But now I am getting an error like-
module.js: 338
   throw err;
Error: Cannot find module 'path to the file'
at Function.module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:25)

Comment: You have probably required a module by giving it a wrong path somewhere in your code. Check your code for all the modules that you have required and see if you've given them right paths.

Comment: Thanks :D I am getting server response now, but while printing the server response to localhost:port it gives me this error and stops in between.

_http_outgoing.js:335
   throw new Error('Can\ 't set headers after they are sent.');

Error: Can't set headers after they are  sent.
At ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setheader(_http_outgoing.js:335:11)

Comment: RESOLVED. But I was using res.json() which was causing this problem? Why is that? I used res.write() and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: I think it's because res.json will  call res.end() which is like trying to send a response back to the client. But your operation isn't completed yet and so you get that error. You should use res.json when you've completed whatever you were trying to do.

Comment: RESOLVED issue. Thanks